# If I remove an app from iTunes Connect will it remove CloudKit Container too?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I am suspicious what happens with `CloudKit Container` when I remove or migrate a project from one team to an other? Maybe this is the way to remove `CloudKit Container`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Containers are linked to a bundle identifier. When you move a project to a different team, you will probably also change the bundle identifier. This will not remove the original container. You will just get an new container for the new identifier.